# Are robots or aliens waiting in Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, fun, robots

It is widely known that aliens is waiting for me in Area 51. However, when I visit the [list of public sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), in the footer it says:
[image: image description]

So officially who is waiting for me there?

Comment: Quite possibly site proposals and a discussion area are awaiting you... then again, they could be inanimate...

Comment: I'm upvoting this because the poster has spotted an inconsistency. Regardless of its triviality, this is still a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All sorts of things await you there. Area 51 isn't only for aliens.

Our Area 51 site also features rocket ships, robots, and a bunch of other weird stuff. In fact, that same robot in your screenshot appears in multiple places on the site, most prominently on the Create Proposal page (which actually features two different robots).